# DB Design: Sort Order for Lookup Tables

Tags: database, language-agnostic, database-design

I have an application where the database back-end has around 15 lookup tables.  For instance there is a table for Counties like this:

```
CountyID(PK)    County
49001       Beaver  
49005       Cache   
49007       Carbon  
49009       Daggett 
49011       Davis   
49015       Emery   
49029       Morgan  
49031       Piute   
49033       Rich    
49035       Salt Lake   
49037       San Juan    
49041       Sevier  
49043       Summit  
49045       Tooele  
49049       Utah    
49051       Wasatch 
49057       Weber
```

The UI for this app has a number of combo boxes in various places for these lookup tables, and my client has asked that the boxes list in this case:

```
CountyID(PK)    County
49035       Salt Lake
49049       Utah
49011       Davis
49057       Weber
49045       Tooele      
'The Rest Alphabetically
```

The best plan I have for accomplishing this is to add a column to each lookup table for SortOrder(numeric).  I had a colleague tell me he thought that would cause the tables to violate 3rd-Normal-Form, but I think the sort order still depends on the key and only the key (even though the rest of the list is alphabetical).

Is adding the SortOrder column the best way to do this, or is there a better way I am just not seeing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with @cletus that a sort order column is a good way to go and it does not violate 3NF (because, as you said, the sort order column entries are functionally dependent on the candidate keys of the table).

I'm not sure I agree that alphanumeric is better than numeric.  In the specific case of counties, there are seldom new ones created.  But there is no requirement that the numbers assigned are sequential; you can allocate them with numbers that are a multiple of a hundred, for example, leaving ample room for insertions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I agree a sort order column is the best solution when the requirements call for a custom sort order like the one you cite. I wouldn't go with a numeric column however. If the data is alphanumeric, the sort order should be alphanumeric. That way you can seed the value with whatever is in the county field.

If you use a numeric field you'll have to resequence the entire table (potentially) whenever you add a new entry. So:

Columns: ID, County, SortOrder

Seed:

```
UPADTE County SET SortOrder = CONCAT('M-', County)
```

and for the special cases:

```
UPDATE County
SET SortOrder = CONCAT('E-' . County)
WHERE County IN ('Salt Lake', 'Utah', 'Davis', 'Weber', 'Tooele')
```

Arguably you may want to put another marker column in to indicate those entries are special.

Comment: Thx - In general my lookup tables are 'static' and the longest so far is this sample for counties at 29 rows.  I am not sure what you mean by 'seed with the value in the county field'.  By that do you mean store the first X characters of the name in the SortOrder column?  Would you then pre-pend an a, b, c or 1, 2, 3 to the string?

Comment: Meaning putting "Utah" or "aUtah" is easier than putting 5 in the sort order column because the alpha value doesn't relate to anything else so can be directly inserted with no dependencies on other values like a numeric sort order would have.

Answer (score 0):

I went with numeric and large multiples.

Even with the CONCAT('E-'.. example, I don't get the required sort order. That would give me Davis, SL, Tooele... and Salt Lake needs to be first.

I ended up using multiples of 10 and assigned the non-special-sort entries a value like 10000.  That way the view for each lookup can have

```
ORDER BY SortOrder ASC, OtherField ASC
```

Another programmer suggested using DECODE in Oracle, or CASE statements in SQL Server, but this is a more general solution.  YMMV.